# Calculating radius for off screen map locations

Tags: android, google-maps, math

### Question:

How can I taken into account the rectangular shape of the screen to ensure that circles are drawn exactly to the padded boundary?

The following works for a 'round' area, but not a rectangular one...

```
dx = abs(center.x - place.x);
dy = abs(center.y - place.y);
dh = Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));
radius = dh - padding;
```

**Halo Design:**
[image: Halo idea]

If the problem doesn't seem apparent, the following image represents the current approach which i'm using. Depending on where the place is effects how far it protrudes into the screen space.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I **think** this should work. Not tested.

```
dx = abs(placeLocationPixels.x - ourLocationPixels.x)
dy = abs(placeLocationPixels.y - ourLocationPixels.y)

ox = dx - ((screenSize.x / 2) - padding);
oy = dy - ((screenSize.y / 2) - padding);

if (ox < 0) ox = 0;
if (oy < 0) oy = 0;

radius = sqrt((ox*ox) + (oy*oy));
```

edit: this is not in any particular language.

Comment: I was about to answer, then saw this guy. Super speedy over here. Looks right to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe you can calculate the convex hull, and then circumscribe it into a rectangle, then you will have the scale of your map to ensure that every circle is shown on the screen.

here: you can find information about the convex hull: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull

Comment: "In mathematics, the convex hull or convex envelope for a set of points X in a real vector space V (for example, usual 2- or 3-dimensional space) is the minimal convex set containing X. "